# Batch with No args runs as job (scheduled task) with no errors, Batch with 1 arg fails with Access Denied. Why?

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2003, scheduled-tasks

Here's a trivial batch:

```
 @echo off
 if not .%1==.-b goto else
 echo Running with -b flag ON 
 goto endif
 :else
 echo Running with NO flags
 :endif
```

---

Now, trying to run this from a scheduled task on a **Windows Server 2003**...

If the task is ran like: "C:\Test\test.bat" then the log (Schedlgu.txt) says:

"Test Job.job" (test.bat)
    Started 7/14/2010 10:27:19 AM
"Test Job.job" (**test.bat**)
    Finished 7/14/2010 10:27:19 AM
    Result: The task completed with an exit code of (0).

However, when running like: "C:\Test\test.bat -b" then:

"Test Job.job" (**test.bat -b**) 7/14/2010 10:28:02 AM ** ERROR **
    Unable to start task.
    The specific error is:
    0x80070005: **Access is denied**.
    Try using the Task page Browse button to locate the application.

---

The task is running under the Admin account (of the domain). I have also granted full access  to this user to the local cmd.exe

Any thoughts why the task fails when running a batch with one argument?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the task with parameters like this:

```
"C:\Test\test.bat" -b
```

Note the different quoting!

The fisrt string inside quotes is always considered the file name, hence the error message you see.